# Does internet speed afect browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I wanted to know if browser speed affects the execution time of JavaScript code.
For example, if I have this code

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
   console.log(i)
}
```

Does it mean that someone with a 4G connection will get this code executed earlier than someone with a 2G connection

Comment: No, but there might be some correlation (money) between someone with a better/faster mobile internet connection and better/faster hardware.

Comment: It probably takes longer for the code to be downloaded into the browser on slower connections. Once it's there, there's no difference.

Comment: Any modern browser can monitor the execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as I understand it, Java Script is run in your browser and your browser have engine to run java script.

Only thing that connection speed can affect is request/response cycle; download of files sent from server.... (html, css, js files...)

Hope this explanation helps?